# Any PHP IDE follow PSR standards?

Tags: php, psr-0, php-ide

Is there any PHP IDE that follow all the rules of PSR 0 to PSR 3 standards as their code formatting standard?

I know all IDEs follow particular code formatting standard but not sure if any are exactly/mostly follow PSR 0 to PSR 3 standards.

Kindly let me know if there is any such PHP IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE PHPStorm
[More PHP Formatting Options and Bundled Code Styles for PSR-1/PSR-2 and Symfony2](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/11/more-php-formatting-options-and-bundled-code-styles-for-ps/)